# How do I get at the metadata of attributed parameters?

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes

How do I get at the attribute of the parameter in the following code?

```
public void SomeMethod([SomeAttribute] string s)
{
    var someAttribute = ?
}
```

And I realize the attribute isn't generally for use inside the method it's on... just keeping the example simple though.

Comment: Wow, the trigger happy downvoters are out tonight I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a `MethodInfo`:

```
var method = typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("SomeMethod");
```

Then you can check for existence:

```
bool hasAttrib = Attribute.IsDefined(
    method.GetParameters()[0], typeof(SomeAttribute));
```

or get an instance (more expensive):

```
var attrib = (SomeAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
    method.GetParameters()[0], typeof(SomeAttribute));
```

Comment: Ugh... I have two wait here two more minutes before I can give you credit for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out:

```
var someAttribute = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("SomeMethod").GetParameters().First().GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

I just had a brain fart and was using the Attributes property instead of the GetCustomAttributes method.

Comment: You could also use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`

Comment: @leppie it is unlikely that you would need to query the *current method* for its metadata. By definition... you kinda know that already.

Comment: @leppie I did sort of indicate that I wasn't 'actually' going to be using it inside the method though, haha :)